# How to fix JSX/React formatting issue with Prettier in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, prettier

This is how I want my code to format

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But when I alt+shift+F to format with prettier, I get this (which is incredibly frustrating!!)

```
render() {
  return <div>{this.state}</div>;
}
```

It's not TOO bad in this particular situation, but I'd rather fix it now before I get into anything too complicated.

Does anyone know which settings I can can change to fix this? I've been looking around for a while and can't find anything helpful.

Comment: what is wrong with how it is formatting right now? because it is one line it will format it to be one line, as your file progresses just ensure that your return parantheses wraps your jsx....

Comment: I'd rather just have it set up with parens and multiple lines... If I start putting in multiple layers of html, I'd rather have it not be on one line. I also just switched to prettier from beautify, cause that was making things REALLY wonky, so I'm not sure how this effects actual HTML files, but I prefer to have my tags broken apart like this for my own readability.

Comment: if you go to another line it won't be one line

Comment: if your return becomes more than one line it will break them up into multiple lines....

Answer (score 1):

Prettier is an opinionated formatter so there isn't a lot of flexibility outside of [these configuration settings](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html).

I wouldn't worry though, the reason its formatted like that is because it can fit all of it on a single line without going outside of the column range of 100, if you try adding another div or something you'll notice that it will not do this, and so more complex scenarios is not going to be problematic.